# Direct Uploads to S3 using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've recently converted the below from using Paperclip to Carrierwave uploading to Amazon S3 so I can make use of the carrierwave_direct gem and then Sidekiq or another background processing gem.

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks, :order => "releases_tracks.position DESC"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases_tracks  
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :track, TrackUploader
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :releases, :through => :releases_tracks 
end
```

/views/releases/track_upload.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@release, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<h3>Upload Tracks for <%= @release.title %></h3>
    <% index = 0 %>
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
    <%= @release.tracks[index].name %>
        <%= f.file_field :track, :class => "file styled", :title => 'Select Track'%>
    <% index += 1 %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Upload Tracks", :class => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Carrierwave uploads are working, but I can't figure out how to get the direct part working. Partly because I can't figure out how to incorporate the suggested form code:

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :track %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %
```

Or the where in my track OR release controller I place the suggested:

```
@uploader = User.new.track
@uploader.success_action_redirect = new_user_url
```

The readme https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct and Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3 both point towards uploading your file first and then creating your database entry. In my app the db entries already exist. The Railscast does say it's possible but doesn't go through it. So that's the first problem.

The second is that I need to upload more than one file at a time. The code above does achieve that, but very slowly and it of course renders my app pretty useless as it does so.

Can anyone help? Massive thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20):

First of all I would advise you not to use carrierwave_direct, I really don't like this gem, for many reasons.
One of those reasons, is that as it's said in the docs

> Please be aware that this gem only supports single
>   file uploads. If you want to upload multiple files simultaneously
>   you'll have to use a javascript or flash uploader.

But if you want to use it, here is what I guess you have to do :

So first about the

```
@uploader = User.new.track
@uploader.success_action_redirect = new_user_url
```

It seems you are trying to upload tracks, and as you said your models have already been created, I guess your are trying to upload new tracks for an existing release. Correct me if I'm wrong.

so you should create the `@uploader` var in the `#track_upload` method of your `ReleasesController`.

```
class ReleasesController
  ...  
  def track_update 
    @uploader = User.new.track
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_user_url
  end
  ...
end
```

then in the associated view (`/views/releases/track_upload.html.erb`), you can use the `direct_upload_form`

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :track %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form will upload the file directly to s3, just after you selected the file. Then I don't know exactly how, but carrierwave_direct should give you back the url of the uploaded file.
I'm not sure about that as I've never been that far with it, but the idea is that your file just got uploaded to s3, now it has to be linked to your model, so the file doesn't get 'lost'.
So maybe carrierwave_direct is doing things on its own (I doubt that ...) by doing some ajax requests or anything else.

Anyway as you want to upload more than one file, I'd like to point you to a [tutorial I recently wrote](https://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3)

This shows how to upload files directly to s3, without carrierwave_direct, but by doing things on your own. This requires a little bit more code and time, but you have more control about what's happening.

In your case, you'll want to put the form I'm using in my tutorial in your view, in the /views/releases/track_upload.html.erb view.
Then once you'll select a file, the successful AJAX request(emitted by the jQueryFileUpload plugin) will give you the URL of the uploaded file so you can save it in your Track model (you'll probably want to emit a new AJAX request to your server to create the new Track model, or to populate an other form on the page, like the one you were using in the /views/releases/track_upload.html.erb file, and then the tracks will be saved on submit.)
I'm not sure I'm really clear about that, let me know if you need more explanations.

And the good thing about that is that if you simply add `multiple` to your file input, then the awesome [jQueryFileUpload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin will send a request per file to s3, then you'll get the URL's of the uploaded files in each ajax results :D

And you can tweak things to add progress bars, and things like that with the jQuery plugin, you can really create awesome things.

Hope it'll help you !

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great answer. I think your tutorial is closer to what I am trying to achieve so I will work through it now. I'll feedback on how I get on with it. thanks again!

Comment: Hi Pjam, great tutorial! I'm working through it now and have two questions. In the form tag, should 'data-direct-upload' be class='data-direct-upload'? Also, where should I place the JS that sets the form's key values etc?

Comment: So first, the data attribute was just a way to select the form, you can of course use a class if you prefer it. Then about where to put the js, there's no perfect answer to that, but I'd suggest creating a new js file direct_upload.js for instance, and then it'll be required automatically by your manifest ( application.js ) if you kept the require_tree instruction or you can require it manually otherwise. Be careful to apply the behavior only to the form you want to us for the direct upload , via a class or a data attribute or anything else. If you have any other questions, let me know !!

Comment: Just to let you know that I made some fixes on the post and I answered a few questions, so you should check, it'll probably help you

Comment: I definitely agree with your first statement. I will *never* use carrierwave_direct again. I plan to implement an uploader from scratch next time I need one and expect it to take less time and work much better.

Comment: Maybe you could check this gem https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload it looks really interesting :

Comment: Thanks. Short and readable. I like that. I'm growing more skeptical of the overly-complex, modular architecture of Rails plugins. It makes simple tasks complex and complex tasks elegantly simple—as long as you never have to mess with anything. Once I've ensured we're not losing any more data off of our production server, I'll take a look. FYI, there's just lots of weird stuff going on. Underscores in S3 bucket names (which should be permissible under us-east buckets) fail… sometimes. Filenames with whitespace seem to fail out of the box, and renaming brought on a lot of headaches. Argh.

Comment: For your carrierwave_direct answer, you need to set success_action_redirect to a POST track_update action, which will assign the key to model