# Rails background image upload causing application timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, sidekiq

**Unfortunately the bounty was awarded to an answer that does not solve this problem, for those with similar issues.**

I have a form with an image upload (heroku to s3). When I submit the form, my rails server waits for the background job that uploads the image to finish before returning a response to the user. This causes an application timeout every single time there is an image upload.

Current order of events:

1. User submits form
2. Server receives form
3. If there is an image, server starts a background job
4. If a background job was started, the server waits for it to complete (*rails times out here*)
5. If started, the background job completes
6. The server processes the request
7. The server responds to the user

Desired order of events:

1. User submits form
2. Server receives form
3. Server processes non-image fields
4. If there is an image, server starts a background job
5. The server responds to the user
6. The background job completes and the server processes the uploaded image (saves URL)

**Uploader code**

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
  storage :fog
end
```

**Carrierwave::Backgrounder initializer**

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader, delayed: true
  process_in_background :photo
end
```

There is no controller code because the form is handled by ActiveAdmin. I can override wherever is needed, but have not been able to figure out what needs to change.

What do I have to change to get the correct order of events?

Comment: Forgive me if I've completely misunderstood this problem, but won't uploads not be asynchronous if done via a standard HTML form submission? Doesn't this require some javascript to handle the upload asynchronously, something like this? https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Comment: All the tutorials and resources I've looked at for async image uploads did not change the HTML form generated, just the controller. As I mentioned **the image upload works fine**. The controller that process the form just needs to not wait.

Comment: Sorry, I'd need to see more code to understand how you are trying to implement this. Is the sidekiq worker handling the entire upload to S3 or just being queued when the upload is done to handle the DB update? What does your controller look like that responds to the form submission?

Comment: None of that *should* matter because it's all working fine. I just need the controller to not wait for the async image upload. ActiveAdmin is handling the form, with a standard uploader (carrierwave). There is absolutely nothing special about this setup aside from ActiveAdmin.

Comment: So you're saying that with a non-ActiveAdmin setup, standard Rails controllers inheriting (directly or indirectly) from ActionController::Base, the upload will work asynchronously, that the controller action will not block until the upload completes?

Comment: I've re-worded the entire question for clarity. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you please show us your ``CarrierWave::Backgrounder`` initializer ?

Also, to be sure, you are using delayed job or any other kind of background processing job, are you ?

Comment: MishieMoo i'm wondering if and why are you not using carrierwave_direct or carrierwave_backgrounder as they process the upload asynchronously.

Comment: @MishieMoo how are you making it async?? You need to add custom controller code for that resource in the active_admin resource file within controller do ... end block for that particular action that's handling form submission

Comment: @Intrepidd Added the initializer. It's really not special at all.

Comment: @FurqanAsghar Carrierwave::Backgrounder is handling the async processing. I don't know how to update the controller code to get the desired order of events, that is the point of this question.

Comment: ah, @MishieMoo did you look at this http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#collection_actions look at the bottom of the page "Modify the controller" you can override all the rest actions inside that block or even create your own if it's a non-rest action

Comment: @FurqanAsghar I know *how* to override the controller. I do not know *what* to change to get the correct sequence to happen. I need to modify how the request is processed and the documentation you linked does not help.

Comment: Was reading the docs on carrierwave_backgrounder gem. Some confusion  between process vs. process & store. Is it possible that you aren't backgrounding the storage, only the processing? Maybe its not possible to background storing the file since you are using Heroku + S3?

Comment: Just as a sanity check sidekiq is running async jobs from a redis queue in whatever environment you are testing this in right? There's no stray call to `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` which might be applying to unexpected environments?

Comment: I tailed my Heroku logs to double check. The Sidekiq process is happening on the worker machine, with async queues. And we don't use `Sidekiq::Testing` anywhere. The file upload happens on the main box to a temp location on Heroku, then the worker moves it from Heroku to s3. That second part is what's causing the timeouts, and many articles suggest this setup to use on Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

The underlying issue here is Heroku has strict limits on how long a request may block without sending data back to the client.  If you hit that limit (30 seconds for the initial byte), Heroku will timeout your request.  For file uploads, it is very likely you will hit this limit.

The best approach is to have the user's browser directly upload the file to S3 first.  There is some discussion here that is relevant to this: [Direct Uploads to S3 using Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724826/direct-uploads-to-s3-using-carrierwave)

If you use something like the jQuery File Upload plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), the flow would be something like:

- User adds one or more files to the form before clicking submit.
- The files are uploaded directly to S3 and a file upload token is added for each file to your form.
- User submits form with the tokens of the uploaded files rather than the contents of the files.
- The server can move the files to their real home in S3 based on the submitted token.

This allows your web server to focus on just serving the request and not block on file uploads which can take a long time.

This requires a bit more work due to Heroku's limits - but ultimately I think is your only option to avoid the timeout limits.

Also, I'd recommend you create an upload S3 bucket and then set an S3 lifecycle policy to purge files older than some interval.  When you are doing direct file uploads, it is common for some uploads to not be processed due to the user giving up etc, so the lifecycle does the job of cleaning up these files.

Comment: We don't want to use javascript/jQuery for this. Ideally we can modify the request processing to respond to the user while the file is uploading to s3 in the background.

Comment: If you are using the default Rails server on Heroku it is limited to one request per dyno so you may be able to do your threaded approach by switching to unicorn or puma which support multiple web processes per dyno.  The safest approach long-term though is the direct file upload.  I agree it is not as convenient but that is just one of the downsides of using Heroku.  I just found this article by them as well - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

Comment: We are already using Unicorn, so the request limit per dyno shouldn't be a problem. The article you linked uses the jQuery solution =/